# Unlock the encrypted Volumes after restarting the server via SSH

Tags: ssh, password, disk-encryption, remote-control

I used the `sudo shutdown -r` to restart my Mac server via SSH. However, after restarting the server, I discovered that two volumes are offline due to encryption.

[image: Info of diskutil list]

What I am trying to do is input the password via `ssh` to unlock the encrypted disks in order to resume the functionality of the server. Could anyone help me figure out how to execute this command via `ssh`?

Answer (score 0):

Once you have `ssh`ed into the system, use `diskutil`. If you are using a passphrase, you can append `-stdinpasspharse` for the tool to prompt the passphrase. Otherwise, you can include the passkey using just `-passphrase`.

`diskutil corestorage unlockVolume $volumeIdentifier -passphrase /path/to/passkey`

-OR-

`diskutil corestorage unlockVolume $volumeIdentifier -stdinpassphrase`

Here, `$volumeIdentifier` is the ID such as the one starting with `7EB3514D-`. If you want to decrypt the drive (that is, making it no longer encrypted), you can use `decryptVolume` instead. The format is the same, as follows.

`diskutil corestorage decryptVolume $volumeIdentifier -stdinpassphrase`

-OR-

`diskutil corestorage decryptVolume $volumeIdentifier -passphrase /path/to/passkey`